# Good Practice Gradle Flavors With Class

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I am looking for informations about how I should use gradle flavors to define my behaviors for an Android Application.

> Let's say I want to start a new activity in my flavor1 and not in
>   my flavor2.

As gradle doesn't override classes with each other,

I have to, define the Activity in each flavors

```
app/src/
     |-> flavor1/java/<package>/Activity.java
     |-> flavor2/java/<package>/Activity.java
     |-> main/java/<package>
```

or, define it in my main folder and use an enum in a Constant class which return if I am in my flavor1 or my flavor2

```
app/src/
     |-> flavor1/java/<package>/Constant.java
     |-> flavor2/java/<package>/Constant.java
     |-> main/java/<package>/Activity.java
```

My guess is that I have to mix both solutions:

- If I want to create a unique activity in flavor1, I have to create this same class in flavor2 and maybe just `throw RuntimeException("stub!")`
- If I want to call this activity from `main`, I have to use something like `if (Constant.getFlavor() == flavor1)`

In my opinion, this is the coolest way to use gradle flavors. But I want to be sure that there is no other best ways, so far discovered, to deal with it before the final implementation.

Is there anyone who blogged something about it or want to give his own opinion ? I would love to read you!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place different AndroidManifest files on each flavor. For example you can define the (let's call it) optional Activity inside the flavor1, the Class that extends the optional Activity just inside the flavor1 and you're done! Please note that the flavor AndroidManifest file must specify only what is different from the main AndroidManifest: in this case, you should include just the `<activity/>` (of course inside an empty `<application/>`)

Comment: About how to check if you can call your Activity or not, yes, you can check the flavor name (I suggest to use the `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` constant), or you can use the `PackageManager.getPackageInfo()` passing the package name of your app to retrieve the list of Activities. When you have the list, you can understand if that Activity is there or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't you mean to define the optional Activity inside the main and extends it in flavor1 ? If not I don't get it.

Comment: No. Define the optional Activity just inside the flavor where you need it. In that flavor, you will have to provide an AndroidManifest declaring the optional Activity, it will be merged for you by 'manifest merger'.

Comment: Ok got it but, in my MainActivity, the calling line of my Flavor1's class will return an error if I build flavor2. Even if it is not in the manifest

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested 2 ways to check what's your flavor. The first: use BuildConfig.FLAVOR. It's a constant that is created by the build system. The second: check the Activities of your app using `PackageManager.getPackageInfo()`. If the optional Activity is there, you can start it. But the point is: what you're going to do if you are in flavor2? You should not give the user the possibility to do something that is not handled by that flavor. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid the `if (Constant.getFlavor() == flavor1)` you could create a factory class which then returns the correct intent for that flavours Activity. Then override this in each flavour. This avoids polluting the code with if statements.

Comment: Thanks for the advice